# Selector for not immediate child element

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me what's the selector for finding an element which is within a parent, but not an immediate child. Example:

```
<body class="main">
  <p class="text">Hello</p> <!-- don't select this one -->
  <elem class="something">
    <elem id="link">
      <elem class="otherclass">
        <p class="text">Hello</p> <!-- but this one -->
      </elem>
    </elem>
  </elem>
</body>
```

so I want to find `.text` via `.main` without knowing the number of elements in between and with pure CSS.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you go for `.main .text{}`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could use the following selector:

```
.main > * .text
```

Which will select all `.text` elements that are descendants of `.main`, but not immediate children.

Comment: Nice one, especially because it won't select a `.text` that is a direct child. `+1`

Comment: @LinkinTED Pretty sure that's what the OP wanted, considering the title said *"non-immediate child element"*. It's slightly unclear though.

Comment: +1 you could be right although the wording does have an air of ambiguity in which the simple `.main .text` answer could be valid.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes your solution works indeed, but I have to guarantee that only `.text`s get selected which are at least child childs of the `body`! This is, I guess, the most elegant way!

Comment: Fair enough, no worries in that case this is definitely the answer you want!

Answer (score 6):

You can use simply for all client element:

```
.main .text
{
/*css*/
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f8fuLbvq/)

for avoiding **descendants element(intermediate child)** you should add * between like:

```
.main * .text
{
/*css*/
}
```

[**Featured DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f8fuLbvq/2/)